# Regular expression to match string starting with and numbers in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have strings like :

```
merge_req_title1 = "JARVIS-17442: Enable Fees report"
merge_req_title2= "Resolve JARVIS-15887 'integration new'"
```

i am using python to extract the substring out of them which is as `JARVIS-<number>`

example output for below strings will be as ;

```
merge_req_title1 = "JARVIS-17442: Enable Fees report" -o/p->  "JARVIS-17442"
merge_req_title2= "Resolve JARVIS-15887 'integration new'"  -o/p-> "JARVIS-15887"
```

Any idea for the regex and doing it in python script

below is code what i tried in

```
import re

merge_req_title1 = "JARVIS-17442: Enable Fees report"
merge_req_title2= "Resolve JARVIS-15887 'integration new'"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reg_ex= "\b(JARVIS)-\d{5}\b"
    searched_element = re.search(reg_ex ,merge_req_title1)
    print(searched_element)
```

But i am getting output as none in

Comment: please make an attempt, and share before asking for help

Comment: `\b` is the backspace character, either write `"\\b..."` or use a raw-string `r"\b..."`. Raw String are very handy for RegEx where lots of backslashes are needed.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the regex you need will be `JARVIS-\d+`.

I tested it with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6GgLbU/1) and the following code :

```py
import re

regex = 'JARVIS-\d+'
string = "JARVIS-17442: Enable Fees report"

result = re.match(regex, string)

if result is None:
    print("Regex found nothing")
else:
    print(result[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming, it is not always JARVIS

```
import re
s = "Resolve JARVIS-15887 'integration new'"
p = r'\b[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+\b'
r = re.search(p, s)
if r is None:
    print("No result")
else:
    print(s[r.start():r.end()])
```